Pulling Data from Multiple data.frames into a new one
I have imported a list of excel files and created a dataframe for each that follows the format df_x where x is a unique number (eg. df_1, df_2 ... df_100). All of the excel files (and thus dataframes) have an identical format and I need to pull the data from specific cells into a new dataframe. For example, the first column of my new dataframe (new_df) is row 13 column 2 from every dataframe, the second column of new_df is row 13 column 4 from every data frame, and the third column of new_df is row 13 column 6 from every dataframe.
I've done this successfully in a very manual way, but I'm hoping to use a loop to avoid making errors and to be able to add more excel files easily later on.
The manual code looks like this:
new_df[nrow(new_df) + 1,] <- c(df_1[13,2], df_1[13,4], df_1[13,6])

new_df[nrow(new_df) + 1,] <- c(df_2[13,2], df_2[13,4], df_2[13,6])

I'm struggling to figure out how to make a loop that would run this for all dataframes at once so that I don't need to copy and paste this 100 times, replacing df_1 with df_2 and then def_3 and so on.
I've tried using lapply() and for() loops but I'm a novice when it comes to R and can't figure out how to adapt these to my need.

Maybe you can use mget like below
new_df <- do.call(
    rbind,
    lapply(
        mget(paste0("df_", 1:100)),
        \(x) x[13, c(2, 4, 6)]
    )
)


This generally worked, thank you! Except I only used the three cells as examples and some are in different rows than 13. How would I use this format to reference row 25 column 4 as the next column in new_df?

@CoryDowd probably you can use c(x[13, c(2, 4, 6)], x[25, 4])
